# initializate value only once before all tests runs

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt, specs2

I want to initializate value only once before all tests runs

Now the value `insertDbScheme` create scheme in every test, if it possible to run it only once. Insert scheme from sbt task not suitable

I have two tests

test1:

```
class Test1 extends Specification with InsertDbScheme {

  "test" in {
    insertDbScheme
    // some code
    ok
  }
}
```

test2:

```
class Test2 extends Specification with InsertDbScheme {

  "test" in {
    insertDbScheme
    // some code
    ok
  }
}
```

and a base trait that insert scheme to database

```
trait InsertDbScheme {

  lazy val insertDbScheme = {
    println("insert scheme to database")
  }
}
```

result of running tests

```
insert scheme to database
insert scheme to database
[info] Test1
[info] 
[info] + test
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for specification Test1
[info] Finished in 152 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] 
[info] Test2
[info] 
[info] + test
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for specification Test2
[info] Finished in 152 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
[info] 
[info] ScalaCheck
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[success] Total time: 12 s, completed May 18, 2017 6:35:21 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `object` to make sure it's `lazy val` is only instantiated once:

```
trait InsertDbScheme {
  import InsertDbScheme._
  lazy val insertDbScheme = insertDbSchemeOnce
}

object InsertDbScheme { 
  lazy val insertDbSchemeOnce = {
    println("insert scheme to database")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to use a variable in a `InsertDbScheme` object:

```
trait InsertDbScheme {

  def insertDbScheme = synchronized {
    if (!InsertDbScheme.done) {
      println("insert scheme to database")
      InsertDbScheme.done = true
    }        
  }
}

object InsertDbScheme {
  var done = false
}
```